# Development stopped: Is truecrypt unsecure?

Tags: truecrypt, development

I was looking for truecrypt today and found this:
http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

The page layout changed and claims "**truecrypt is unsecure**". Futher:
"The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft terminated support of Windows XP"

My Questions:

1. What are the risks for still using truecrypt?
2. Will there be any fork of truecrypt?
3. Is Windows "BitLocker" trustable?
4. Is the reason why the development stopped reliable?
5. Which independent alternatives are there for Linux, MacOS and
   Windows?

Comment: It still [unclear](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/05/true-goodbye-using-truecrypt-is-not-secure/) what really happened with trucrypt.  Certainly previous versions of truecrypt are still safe to run, but I would not recommend running the version currently available from the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many believe this to be a hoax, or "canary" - meaning some agency subpoenaed them and they have to be silent about, and it this is a way of speaking about it.

1. At the moment if you are on 7.1a or before this is unknown until the
   source audit is complete.  DO NOT download the current "7.2" version.
2. It is a possibility when things have been figured out behind this.
3. No!  Microsoft has a history of allowing US government access to their encryption products.  This is the reasoning for believing this whole TC end of development is a ruse of some sort.
4. None yet.  The audit will tell.
5. Linux has LUKS, which is also open source, and there are Windows drivers available for it; however, I'm unaware of one for OSX

This is the TC  audit page, still in progress:  http://istruecryptauditedyet.com.
So far they say it looks OK, just a few encryption options may be vulnerable to easier cracking.

Comment: Do you have any reliable sources to support your claims?

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/11/microsoft-nsa-collaboration-user-data  http://gizmodo.com/confirmed-nsa-paid-google-microsoft-others-millions-1188615332